# Checking if element is present when scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape

I'm trying to pull reviews from open table on some restaurants but am getting a TypeError because some of these restaurants don't have reviews.

My current code is:

```
ratings = restDOM.by_id("RestPopLabel_ReviewsFormat")[0].attributes
ratings = ratings['title']
```

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if restDOM.by_id("RestPopLabel_ReviewsFormat")[0] is present
    ratings = restDOM.by_id("RestPopLabel_ReviewsFormat")[0].attributes
    ratings = ratings['title']
else 
    ratings = 'not available'
```

What would be the best way to implement the if statement?

Comment: If anything you should be getting a `SyntaxError`, as there are no colons after your if/else statement (unless this was unintentional)

Comment: Don't check if the element is present. Try to use it and then catch the appropriate error when it fails, [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html).

Comment: What is more precisely data scraping? What is restDOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben's answer is correct here, but I thought I'd expand with actual code:

```
try:
  ratings = restDOM.by_id("RestPopLabel_ReviewsFormat")[0].attributes
  ratings = ratings['title']
except KeyError:
  ratings = 'not available'
```